# Cache Control gets ignored

Tags: java, http, okhttp

I am currently working with Retrofit and Okhttp and I am trying to cache some GET responses.
My Code is:

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    File cacheDir = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"),
            "ddcache");
    HttpResponseCache cache = new HttpResponseCache(cacheDir, 2024);
    okHttpClient.setResponseCache(cache);
    OkClient cl=new OkClient(okHttpClient);
    restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(API_URL)
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .setClient(cl).build();
```

And the Log shows this header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: max-age=7200
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Tue, 18 Mar 2014 18:38:16 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=3, max=100
OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1395167895452
OkHttp-Response-Source: NETWORK 200
OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1395167895378
Server: Apache/2.2.26 (Unix)
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.28
```

I check the response by returning the Server Unix Time on every call and it always returns a new one which means the

> Cache-Control: max-age=7200

gets totally ignored
The Journal File in the Cache gets also updated with "CLEAN" and "DIRTY" notes, but nothing gets cached.
Is there something obvious I do not see?

Comment: What does your request look like? I was unable to reproduce the problem in a test. https://gist.github.com/swankjesse/a2fba4b1277b4cf4c973

Comment: Ok, I tried your example and it cached something in the given folder. Maybe its something with the Server Time or what ever.If I look into the journal file it gets written but instantly deleted.

Comment: Ahh, my guess is that you aren't reading the full HTTP response body, which causes the cache response to be aborted. Are you using OkHttp 1.5.2? It might fix.

Comment: Yep. I am using OkHttp 1.5.2 together with newest RetroFit. So I guess I do read the full request. As proposed [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/HttpResponseCache.java) I do add the max-stale header to my request but still the requests wont get cached.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had a similar problem. The size of the cache is set in kilobytes and you are setting it to only 2024 kilobytes. That not enough space for almost anything. Try setting it to "10L * 1024 * 1024" (10Mb) and see if that helps.

Comment: You got a good point there. Will try it later and report back. Currently using some custom-hacky approach I dont feel confortable with.